# How to query between 2 specific hours of the day

Tags: postgresql, date-arithmetic, sql-timestamp

Need to query only results from a table where a specific time is only between 10:00am EST and 09:59pm EST.

Using this query example:

```
SELECT
s.id as "ID",
to_char(s.started_at AT TIME zone 'UTC-5', 'HH12:MIam') as "Start_time",
FROM
stats s
WHERE
s.started_at IS NOT NULL
```

Does anyone have a WHERE statement that would show those results regardless of DATE?

Answer (score 1):

Cast the column to `time`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM states s
WHERE CAST ((s.started_at AT TIME ZONE 'EST') AS time)
      BETWEEN TIME '10:00' AND TIME '21:59';
```